# Error using networkx weighted edgelist

Tags: python, networkx, weighted-graph

I have created a weighted edge list that I am trying to use to generate a weighted undirected graph:

The data is in a csv which looks like the following in excel:

```
node1 node2 weight

a     b     0.1

a     c     0.3
```

As recommended by other StackOverflow posts, I have been using the following code to read in the csv:

```
fh=open("<file_location>.csv", 'r')
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(fh,delimiter=',')
```

The first line runs fine but the second yields the error message:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert weight data weight to type type 'float'
```

If I check G, it has read in the nodes fine but not the weights, any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with file format vs what `read_weighted_edgelist` expects. So, 1)show the file as it is, not how it "looks in Excel"; 2) _"If I check G, it has read in the nodes fine but not the weights"_ - show here what tells you so.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your comment, I'm new to this so any help is much appreciated. 1)The data is in a csv with three columns, is there a way that I can look at it as it is without it opening in excel?  2)  If I call nx.info(G) it returns 'Name: \nType: Graph\nNumber of nodes: 53\nNumber of edges: 1378\nAverage degree:  52.0000'

Comment: 1) open it with anything other than Excel, duh! Google that.

Comment: Sorry just got there: a_node1,b_node2,c_weight
firstname_secondname,firstname_secondnames,0.103883495146
firstname_secondname,firstname_secondname,0.105935386927
firstname_secondname,firstname_secondname,0.134917267713

Comment: As [read_weighted_edgelist — NetworkX 1.10 documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_weighted_edgelist.html) says, the format it expects is not CSV but delimiter-separated data, with whitespace as the default delimiter. If you have another delimiter, pass it as the corresponding argument.

Comment: Hi Ivan, sorry I'm missing something here, can you explain why my data is not in the right format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** restructured to include explanation for why code fails and how to resolve, following @Joel's suggestion. <s>@Joel's answer provides an explanation of why the code fails, but not a suggestion for how to move resolve it.</s>

## **Solution**

`nx.read_weighted_edgelist` will ignore input lines that start with `#`, so if you change the first line of your csv file from

```
node1 node2 weight
```

to

```
#node1 node2 weight
```

then you should be able to read in the network with weights.

Also note that `read_weighted_edgelist` accepts a file path (string) as well as a file handle, so if you aren't using `fh` again, you don't need to open it first, just pass it directly.

```
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist("<file_location>.csv", delimiter=',')
```

## **Why your code failed**

(this is incorporated from the answer of @Joel)

When it encounters the first line (from your comments: `a_node1,b_node2,c_weight` )

it interprets the first node to be `a_node1`, the second to be `b_node2`, and it tries to assign the weight `c_weight` to the edge between them.

It is difficult to convert the string `c_weight` to a float.  So it gives an error.

Comment: glad it helped! - if this (or other solutions solve your problem, you can mark it as accepted with the green tick.

Comment: @Bonlenfum - could you edit my response into your answer?  It would be better to have a single complete answer than two partial answers.

Answer (score 1):

When it encounters the first line (from your comments: `a_node1,b_node2,c_weight` )

it interprets the first node to be `a_node1`, the second to be `b_node2`, and it tries to assign the weight `c_weight` to the edge between them.

It is difficult to convert the string `c_weight` to a float.  So it gives an error.